# On summability of functions in weighted Lebesgue spaces

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I consider a (continuous) function $V \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $V \geq 1$ and $\lim_{|x|\to +\infty} V(x)=+\infty$. Let $u$ be a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$\int V(x) |u(x)|^2 \, dx < \infty.$$

Let now $p>2$ be a real number. Under what (general) assumptions on $V$ and possibly on $u$ can we conclude that $$\int V(x) |u(x)|^p \, dx$$ is also finite?

It seems to me that some additional condition must be imposed, since $p>2$. I do not know how to use the condition that $V$ diverges at infinity (and maybe this condition is useless here). Any idea or suggestion?

The case $V \to 0$ at infinity seems to be more popular in the literature, but I am working in the opposite setting.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question is pretty broad, i do not know whether my answer will be satisfying to you. Please let me know whether the following fits your criteria or whether you want a different approach:

My impression is that one would need to impose some "growth condition" on $V$ together with some "moment condition" on $u$, in the following sense:

Asssume there exists some $\gamma>0$ such that $$\lim_{|x|\to\infty} \frac{V(x)}{|x|^\gamma}=0,$$ which intuitively means that $V$ does not grow faster that $|x|^\gamma$. Now let's also assume (and this is an assumption for a fixed $p$) that $u$ satisfies the moment condition $$\int |x|^{2\gamma}\cdot |u(x)|^{2(p-1)}dx<\infty.$$ Then by a simple application of Cauchy-Schwartz together with the realization that $\int |u(x)|^2dx$ must be finite, due to the fact that $V\geq 1$, we get: $$\begin{align*}\int V(x)|u(x)|^pdx&\leq C\int |x|^\gamma|u(x)|^pdx = C\int |x|^\gamma |u(x)|^{p-1}\cdot|u(x)|dx \\ (\text{Cauchy-Schwartz})&\leq\bigg(\int |x|^{2\gamma}|u(x)|^{2(p-1)}dx\bigg)^{1/2}\bigg(\int |u(x)|^2 dx\bigg)^{1/2}<\infty.\end{align*}$$ Alternatively, one could derive similar conditions by using [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) instead of the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. It may be worthwile to try Hölder's inequality with different exponents to see if you can get a sufficient condition that suits your problem. I.e. you can exchange how strong either the "growth condition" on $V$ is or how strong the integrability condition on $u$ is depending on which exponents you choose.

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to @SmallDeviation we now know that the original proof does not work, you have to add supplementary conditions on the asymptotic behavior of $u$ since measurable functions are a very wide set of functions, there are critical errors. I have various ideas of condition but finding an explicit necessary and sufficient condition seems impossible.

Here is a suitable counterexample:
$$V = \|x\| + 1$$
$$u = \sum_{n >0} n \cdot 1_{\left[n, n + \frac{1}{n^{4 +\epsilon}}\right]}$$
with $\epsilon >0$.

The end was pure garbage thus I suppressed it (I only leave my answer for the counter example, however $u \to 0$ is a cool condition to add

Comment: I believe there Is a problem with the integrale over $B$. Why Is It finite?

Comment: The statement $u \to 0$ should be replaced with something which takes into account sets of measure zero.

Comment: @Siminore It is finite since $B$ is compact. Plus $u$ is obviously unbounded on a set of null measure otherwise $\int Vu^2$ would diverge. There is no problem here just prove it by yourself and you will see…

Comment: Yes obviously the limits are defined on a set whose complementary has null measure. In reality we don’t really care, you can directly work in the quotiented space since the results are on integrals

Comment: I really can't see why $u\to 0$ would be true. Consider dimension $n=1$ and choose $V(x)=|x|+1$ as well as $u(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb 1_{[n,n+2^{-n}]}(x)$. If i am not mistaken, $V$ and $u$ fulfill all of the assumptions, but $u\not\to 0$.

Comment: @SmallDeviation Indeed I was too quick I'll add a warning

Comment: @JulesBesson B is compact, but you are changing the exponent of $u$. It seems to me that the integral over $B$ is problematic

Comment: @Siminore if $u$ is bounded, so is $u^p$ for any $p$, if your space has finite measure, the integral will be finite, the real problem is what  Small Deviation mentioned...

Comment: @JulesBesson $u$ need not be bounded at all. There are unbounded functions which are locally integrable.

Comment: @Siminore Yes sorry, I'm tired... thank you for being stubborn :) have a nice day. Hopefully I (finally) added the continuity in my post

Comment: @JulesBesson Thank you for editing your answer. Although now you mention that $u\to0$ for continuous functions. I still do not think this is true, even assuming continuity of $u$ and $V$. Could you include a proof of this? My thinking is that one could easily modify the counterexample i gave by e.g. convolving it with a gaussian kernel, thus obtaining a "continuous version" of my function, which still does not go to $0$.

Comment: Of course you're right, you could even make small bumps as far as you want I am totally wrong :(